# How can I change source directory from System 32?

Tags: home-directory, paths

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. When I open my terminal, the source path (directory) starts with System32, how can I change it to User or Desktop ?
When I type cmd.exe :
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1320]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

Comment: Can you add some details? In Ubuntu the default directory is `/home/$USER`.

Comment: Yes sure! when I open my terminal the first I see is "System 32" while other colleagues have "User" or "Desktop". I have just now used "cd" command and I am in /home/user. But when i use "ls" i see "Code" in blue, but I don't see any folders. I would just like to have user or desktop when I open the terminal.. Sorry if my question is unclear and thank you for your reply !

Comment: @JihaneElJbari In that terminal, please [edit] your question to include the output of typing in `cmd.exe` and pressing enter.

Comment: @cocomac : done

Comment: So… that is not Ubuntu. That is Windows.

Answer (score 3):

So... Windows is an operating system. Ubuntu is also an operating system. Both are operating systems, but they are *different* operating systems. They both have shells (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/111144/1438484) for the difference between a terminal emulator and a shell). On Windows 10, there are two shells: PowerShell* and `cmd.exe`. PowerShell can do almost everything `cmd.exe` can, as it is far newer. There are several shells on Ubuntu. The one that it uses by default for a user is called `bash`. There is a second one called `sh`, but it is used less, as it is far less powerful, but it is more cross-platform, similar to how PowerShell is newer, but there are also a few old systems that don't have it.

On Windows, when you start a "Command Prompt" (which is just the start menu entry for `cmd.exe`). The default directory that `cmd.exe` (or I think PowerShell, too) is `C:\Windows\System32`.

Here's the interesting bit: In `cmd.exe`, to list files in a directory, you type in `dir` and press enter. On PowerShell, you type in `Get-ChildItem`, and press enter. Here's where it is confusing: there are a handful of aliases in PowerShell (you can get a list with `Get-Alias`). The two that matter here are `dir` and `ls`. Both are aliased to `Get-ChildItem`. This means that when you type in `ls` in PowerShell, it will print the files in the current directory. On Ubuntu, both `dir` and `ls`, *also* print the files in the current directory.

Here's how I know you are using PowerShell on Windows 10:

You mentioned as a comment that `ls` worked (e.g., it listed the files in your current directory). Remember, `ls` only works in PowerShell and `bash` (so not `cmd.exe`). But, you also said `cmd.exe` does something: it starts the `cme.exe` shell. But that only exists on Windows, *not Ubuntu*.

Now to answer your question:

On both Windows and Linux, you can change your current directory with the `cd` command. So basically, set your directory with `cd [where you want to go]`. E.g., on Linux, if you wanted to go to the `/etc` directory, you would do `cd /etc`. But if you want Ubuntu, either use something like Windows Subsystem for Linux or download it from the Ubuntu website

*Technically, yes, you can install PowerShell on Linux. But I'm talking about the defaults here.